Flutter retrieve firestore data in model
I have been following a tutorial on creating a food ordering app.
In the tutorial, there is a restaurant model file that includes the the menu items.
final List<Food> _menu = [
  Food(
    name: 'Classic Burger',
    description: 'A half pounder with all the fixins.',
    imagePath: 'lib/images/burgers/burger1.jpg',
    price: 10.99,
    category: FoodCategory.burgers,
    availableAddons: [
      Addon(name: 'Extra cheese', price: 0.69),
      Addon(name: 'Bacon', price: 1.09),
      Addon(name: 'Avocado', price: 2.25),
    ],
  ),

then the getter is
List<Food> get menu => _menu;

I would like to get this data from firestore.
I have created a collection named 'menu'

I have created this future method in the same dart file.
Future<List<Food>> getMenuData() async  {
  CollectionReference menu = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('menu');

  // Get docs from collection reference
  // QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = menu.get() as QuerySnapshot<Object?>;
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await menu.get();

  // Get data from docs and convert map to List
  final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

  return allData as List<Food>;
}

I then updated the getter to
List<Food> get menu => getMenuData();

This generated compile error:

A value of type 'Future<List>' can't be returned from the function 'menu' because it has a return type of 'List'.

So how can I get the menu loaded from firestore instead of hard coded in the model file?

You will need to loop through your data to set it to the model Food.

// Get docs from collection reference
// QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = menu.get() as QuerySnapshot<Object?>;
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await menu.get();

// Get data from docs and convert map to List
final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

return List<Food>.from(allData?.map((x) =>     Food(
     name: x[“name”],
    description: x[“description”],
    imagePath: x[“imagePath”],
    price: x[“price”],
    // The rest of your values
);
    ));


I added the return statement with allData. instead of allDAta?.

the snapshot doc comes as a map,  even when they match… A map data type is very different from a class model. Hence you have to cast it within the loop. For ease you can define a fromJson method inside your class model.
